# MarkLogic npm issues

Tags: node.js, npm, marklogic

I'm having issue while I'm installing MarkLogic. When I execute the command

```
npm install marklogic --save
```

I'm getting an error. It says

```
Refusing to install marklogic as a dependency of itself
```

package.json:

```
{ 
  "name": "marklogic", 
  "version": "0.0.0", 
  "private": true, 
  "scripts": { 
    "start": "node ./bin/www" 
  }, 
  "dependencies": { 
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1", 
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3", 
    "debug": "~2.2.0", 
    "express": "~4.13.4", 
    "jade": "~1.11.0", 
    "morgan": "~1.7.0", 
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the package.json file of the project you're working in?

Comment: Here is my package.json file                                                                                     {
       "name": "marklogic",
       "version": "0.0.0",
       "private": true,
       "scripts": {
       "start": "node ./bin/www"
      },
    "dependencies": {
       "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
       "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
       "debug": "~2.2.0",
       "express": "~4.13.4",
       "jade": "~1.11.0",
       "morgan": "~1.7.0",
       "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
      }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Checking -- if you cloned [the MarkLogic Node.js API project](https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api), then ran the npm install command that you show above, I'd expect to see this error. Is that what's happening?

---

Edit: elevating @grtjn's point from the comment: When selecting a name for your package, it has to be unique. "marklogic" is the name of an existing package, and therefore conflicted with the same name used for the package you were building.

Comment: i didnt clone the MarkLogic Node.js API project, when i try to add a parameter --save i get those error but when i install marklogic globally it install successfully.

Comment: Your package.json has name `marklogic`. You cannot add a dependency on a module called `marklogic` if you are naming your own project `marklogic` too. You probably want to pick a different name for your own project..